# Calculate number of rating records provided in each year-month

Tags: python, timestamp, mapreduce

My mapper is:

```
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    # split line into the four fields
    fields = line.strip().split("\t")

    value = fields[2] #rating
    key = fields[3] #timestamp in unix seconds
    
    print(key, value, sep="\t")
```

My reducer is:

```
import sys
                                     
(last_key , count) = (None, 0)

for line in sys.stdin:

    (key, value) = line.strip().split("\t")
   
    if  (last_key  and last_key  !=key):
          print(last_key, count, sep="\t")
          count=0
    
    last_key  = key
    count += int(value)
    
          
print(last_key, count, sep="\t")
```

How to I get the number of ratings? The mapper works fine. And when should I convert the timestamp (last_key in this case)

Output should be (year-month \t number of rating records)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reduce (group by) the `year-month` string, that needs to be the key of the mapper, rather than having second-precision.

After that, you just need to count the number of values for that key in the reducer. (The mapper's value can just be `1`, not the actual value, if you only need to *count* the ratings, then the reducer can `sum` the values)

I'd recommend using [`mrjob` library](https://mrjob.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guides/writing-mrjobs.html) rather than manually reading from `sys.stdin`, or you can re-write your code in PySpark and do the same operation in less lines.

Comment: The key of the mapper should be the year, but how will I define in my reducer that the number of ratings are counts? Does this count += int(value) seem right? Or should it look like this: count +=1. Also, I have been using this to convert the time to yyyy-mm, but it does not seem to work: last_key = key.apply(lambda x:
                 datetime.fromtimestamp(x).strftime("%Y-%m"))

Comment: Unclear what you're using apply for here. That's not a string function. You also don't need to track "last key" in the mapper. Just use `key = datetime.fromtimestamp(fields[3]).strftime("%Y-%m"))`... Hard to answer without seeing your data though. Then `print(key, 1, sep="\t")`. Then you can use a `Counter` object in the reducer rather than track individual keys and values

Comment: there are 1 million users rating different movies. The data file has four columns 'userID' 'itemID' 'ratings' 'timestamp'. I split this columns and I define which one the key is and which is the value for the reducer. in this case the key is the 'timestamp' and the value is the 'ratings'. I managed to get the program running, but without converting the timestamp. Otherwise, if I try to convert it, it crushes. I used the code you suggested and still doesn't work.